Problem with attribute names in persistence with JPA
I'm having a problem trying to map database columns to DTO with JPA in my backend.
Some column names are not accepted, I don't know why. This began to occur after the use of quarkus.
When I set the name of my attribute to the one below it doesn't work, it returns null:
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name="status_g_r")
    private String statusGR;

But when I set it to the other one below it works and returns the data correctly:
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name="status_g_r")
    private String status_g_r;

The column name is identical to what I wrote in the note, I don't understand why it doesn't work because some other attributes with similar names work normally, such as:
@Getter
@Setter
@Column(name="status_gh_gj")
private String statusGhGj;

The solution I use temporarily is to use the attribute name identical to the column name in the database, but it is not recommended due to the naming standard. Therefore, I need to change it to use it correctly.

I assume you are using the the following configuration:
quarkus.hibernate-orm.physical-naming-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy

And as such that is the intended behaviour:
The naming strategy only inserts an underscore if the upper case letter is followed by at least one lower case letter.
So in this case, the statusGR is not a match for the behaviour.

How do you think I can fix it? Since this setting is not defined in my application.properties, however it makes sense for it to be the default one being used.

If you do not want to follow the specific Physical naming strategy, then you need to define a custom one and point to it in your application.properties.
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#PhysicalNamingStrategy

or you change your attribute names, so that they match the UppercaseLetterFollowedByLowerCaseLetter rule.
statusHelloWorld, instead of statusHW.
Like I explained.  It is a rule that must be followed.

I get it! Thank you very much, you were very clear.
